# http file upload using cURL in linux(command line)

Tags: php, linux, http, curl

I have to upload the file in my local system using the **CURL** HTTP POST in linux command line.

I have used these commands, with no success:

```
curl -F "image=@/var/www/fbapp/images/registration.png" http://localhost/xmlcreate/curlupload.php

curl --form "fileupload=@/var/www/fbapp/images/registration.png" http://localhost/xmlcreate/curlupload.php

curl -X POST -d @/var/www/fbapp/images/registration.png http://localhost/xmlcreate/curlupload.php

curl --data-binary @/var/www/fbapp/images/registration.png http://localhost/xmlcreate/curlupload.php
```

I used all these commands but none of these worked.

Here is my **PHP** file where I'm trying to get the uploaded file(using curl) and save it in some other directory:

```
<?php
$uploadpath = "images/";
$filedata = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
if ($filedata != '' && $filename != '')
    copy($filedata,$uploadpath.$filename);
?>
```

Can someone please help me with this. I'm stuck here and not able to go forward.

Once it starts working on the local I have to use the remote server URL, instead of the localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
curl -i -F filename=image.jpg -F image=@/path/to/image.jpg http://localhost/xmlcreate/curlupload.php
```

Comment: I got this as output:HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 04 Nov 2014 13:01:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: Was the file uploaded? Since your script doesn't output anything, it's hard to say if it worked or not!

Comment: I tried the same with server connected to the same network.. But it didn't upload it to that server. what else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
move_uploaded_file()
```

I think at least one of your CURL commands work. To check simply put something like:

```
file_put_contents('log.txt',print_r($_FILES,true));
```

in your code and check what you get from curl in real time.